# Bracha change on Tevilas Keilim

Tags: halacha, nuschaot, tevilas-keilim-dipping

[Yoreh Deah 120:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9146&st=&pgnum=39&hilite=) one who Toivels a vessel should make the Bracha "Al Tevilas Keli". However if one Toivels two or more vessels they should make the Bracha "Al Tevilas Keilim". [Aruch HaShulchan Yoreh Deah 120:22](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14242&st=&pgnum=607) disagrees and says one should always say "Al Tevilas Keilim" even if they are only Toveiling one vessel.

To the best of my knowledge I do not know of any other Bracha that we change based on the amount being done. For example, if one affixes one Mezuza or two Mezuzas the Bracha remains the same, ["Likboha Mezuza"](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=229).

Why would the Shulchan Aruch differentiate by Tevilas Keilim from all other instances where the Nusach of the Bracha remains the same regardless of the amount done?

Comment: See the brachot on eiruvin, hafrashas teruma, and I'm pretty sure there's one more but it's escaped me

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30163

Comment: Where do you see that the blessing on Mezuzot is not changed? (Also, there is definitely no 'h' in לקבוע.)

Comment: @DoubleAA: see Rama in link in the question

Comment: I checked every Rama in all your links and can't find such a statement.

Comment: Perhaps, it's because it's not possible to affix multiple Mezuzot simultaneously (i.e., one needs to affix one after another, etc...), whereas it's possible to Tovel many items at the same time (i.e., spread out in a dipping basket, 2 hands used, etc...)